# Will a 9 speed crank work with 10 speed groupset?

Tags: crankset

Will this SLX 9 speed crank work with newer 10 speed groupsets? It looks to me that 9 and 10 speed cranks are the same. Or am I missing something? Are the spaces between the rings different?

[image: Pictured: Shimano 9 speed slx crank]

Comment: The 10 speed chain is narrower. So probably not!

Comment: The question isn't an exact dup but the answers should give you the low-down. Although there are incompatibilities, its worth noting that people out there do run 9/10 mixtures.

Comment: I do run 10 speed m610 crankset with otherwise 9 speed components (from Deore to XT) and everything works just fine, on both two and three crank rings combos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 10 speed crankset has smaller spacing between the rings due to the smaller chain to fit the rear cassette. A nine speed crank set will work with a 10 speed drive train.

However it's not all plain sailing. You can have trouble using a 10 speed FD with a 9 speed crank set. It doesn't shift as far out as the 9 speed so you may experience sloppy changes to the outer ring and chain rub against the FD in some gears. Some people I've heard of run a 9 speed shifter, FD and crank set up on the front and 10 on the back to avoid this but most are happy not to.

Answer (score 1):

10 is a little bit narrower, but generally a crank with 1 measure narrower chain will work pretty good.